Call Google API within Cloud Function with Authentication
I'm trying to call the Dataform API from within a Cloud Function, however the identity token I am providing is returning with a 'Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.'
According to the documentation, the SA running the Cloud Function only needs dataform.workflowInvocations.query permission, which I have granted and confirmed this works when using the Python Dataform library (I need to call the REST API endpoint for a technical reason that the Python library does not provide).
This is the code I am using to make the request with an authorization token, which is what I got from Google themselves here, however using the requests library to make the API call.
import requests
import google.auth.transport.requests
import google.oauth2.id_token

def get_workflow_invocation_actions(environment, git_repo, workflow_invocation_id):
    parent = f"projects/{environment}/locations/europe-west2/repositories/{git_repo}"
    name = f"{parent}/workflowInvocations/{workflow_invocation_id}"

    # The API endpoint
    url = f"https://dataform.googleapis.com/v1beta1/{name}:query"

    auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
    id_token = google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token(auth_req, url)

    # A GET request to the API
    response = requests.get(url, headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {id_token}'})

    # Print the response
    print(response.json())

The id_token does populate with a valid looking token, so I am unsure what is stopping it from authenticating via the REST API.

The error is helpful but unclear. You're (incorrectly) providing an ID token but the Dataform API expects an access token. See Dataform authentication

There's a recommended way for you to solve your problem which is to use Google's Cloud Client library for Dataform (for Python) which not only abstracts the API for you but also handles authentication.

I've not tried this but Google provides google.auth.transports.requests which includes AuthorizedSession which wraps requests and authenticates for you.

@DazWilkin thanks, that's helpful. As mentioned in the post, there is a technical limitation to the Python client library (because the Dataform product team have let it run stale and is now out of sync with the REST API), and the thing I need is only in the REST API

If you're unable to use the Cloud Client Library, you may be able to use the API Client Library (Dataform). The API Client Libraries are generated from the Discovery document and should always be current.
